Get the context (sorted value) of a b-table
I would like to get the information of the context of my b-table.
The table is called like that from my component :
<b-table
...
  :sticky-header="true"
  :responsive="true"
  striped
...
>

And I can see in the vue devtool, when i click on the sort that the "context" of my b-table has the information i need :

How can I get these information into my component ?
Thank you

these are all props that can be provided to b-table.  you may already be doing so... your code example is too simplified to tell.  everything though can be found in the documentation, just search for them, sortBy, sortDesc, filter... the two props perPage and currentPage are related to b-pagination component, also noted in the documentation.

Well maybe I wasn't clear but I could fin dwhat I wanted :
To get the context of my b-table, I had to instatiate it like that :
<b-table
              @context-changed="onContextChange($event)"
      >

and have my function like that :
onContextChange(event: any){
    console.log(event)
  }

And when i click on the sort arrow of my table, it calls my function and show me the "context" of the sort:

